# How to display data from many to many field to a tempate

Tags: python, django, django-orm

My question is similar to [Question on Django: Displaying many to many fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891321/question-on-django-displaying-many-to-many-fields)

The answer given don't help me much !

models.py

```
class MacAddress(models.Model):
      address = models.CharField(max_length = 20,null=True,blank=True)
      def __unicode__(self):
         return self.address

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,primary_key=True,db_index=True)
    MAC=models.ManyToManyField(MacAddress,related_name='macAddress')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

views.py

```
def mac(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    entries = UserProfile.objects.all()
    e = {'posts' : entries }
    return render_to_response('t.html',e, context)
```

t.html

```
{% for post in posts %}
{%  for p in posts.MAC.all %}
{{ p }}
{% endfor %}{% endfor %}
```

How can i display list of mac address corresponding to the a user in t.html

Comment: from my understanding you might be using render_to_response wrong. i think its supposed to be `return render_to_response(request, 'watevertemplate.html', {"name_of_value_you_want_to_call": "value you want to call in your template" } )`, so your dictionary as last argument to render_to_response should probably look like `render_to_response(request, 't.html', {"posts": entries} )` or something similar. not to mention someehow includign context in that dictionary

Comment: @TehTris hey please look into https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response

Comment: oh okay, I see why I thought that. I guess i am more used to just using `render`, hehe

Comment: Why don't the answers help you much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In second for loop you should write `post.MAC.all` . Now you are writing `posts.MAC.all` which is giving you wrong result.

```
{% for post in posts %}
{%  for p in post.MAC.all %} # You should write post.MAC.all instead posts.MAC.all
{{ p }}
{% endfor %}{% endfor %}
```